# Aurelia validating nested objects

Tags: aurelia

I'm trying to validate an object property of an Aurelia ViewModel.

## ViewModel

```
@autoinject
class AddUserForm {
   user: User;
   controller: ValidationController;

    constructor(controllerFactory: ValidationControllerFactory) {
        this.controller = controllerFactory.createForCurrentScope();
    }

    validate() {
        this.controller.validate.then(res => {
            console.log(res.valid);
        })
    }
}

ValidationRules
    .ensure((u: User) => u.id).displayName('User').required()
    .on(AddUserForm)
```

## ViewModel -> View

```
<template>
    <form click.trigger="validate()">
        <input type="text" value.bind="user.id & validate" />
    </form>
</template>
```

## User

```
class User {
    id: string
}
```

The issue I'm having is that the validator is not picking up the nested user object. I'm I missing something to get this working? I read the [docs](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/validation/latest/validation-basics/6) and it seems like this should work. I'm using version `^1.0.0` of the plugin.

Comment: Change to .on(User) instead of .on(AddUserForm)

Comment: @mgiesa How does the validation controller pick up the fact that its validating the User object instead of the currently scoped object?

Comment: if it doesn't pick up the fact that the property "user" is of type User and validate it automatically (I don't remember if it does or not), you can write this.controller.addObject(this.user) in your validate method before calling this.controller.validate()

Comment: I just wrote a few quick tests and I found that you don't need to use .addObject(...) if you have an input trigger validation, in that case the controller just finds the nested object as you'd expect, but you do need to use it if you don't use "& validate" in your markup. I'll post an answer with this info

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in your ValidationRules:

```
ValidationRules
.ensure((u: User) => u.id).displayName('User').required()
.on(AddUserForm)
```

needs to be

```
ValidationRules
.ensure((u: User) => u.id).displayName('User').required()
.on(User)
```

Then to get the controller to run this rule you either need to include "& validate" somewhere in your value.bind *for that property*, like this:

```
<input value.bind="user.id & validate" />
```

or before you call controller.validate(), add the entire object to the controller like this:

```
this.controller.addObject(this.user);
```

I use .addObject *all the time* because it causes validation to run on properties that aren't included in your markup, and I find I prefer that.

Answer (score 0):

This caused an error when I tried it:

```
validate() {
    this.controller.validate(res => {
        console.log(res.valid);
    })
}
```

.validate() expects a ValidateInstruction, in your example you're giving (res: any) => void. I would try changing to this instead:

```
this.controller.validate().then(res => {
    console.log(res.valid);
});
```

Leaving .validate() undefined will cause it to validate all objects and bindings, and .then() will execute after that validation has completed. 
This worked for me when I tried it in my test project.

If I misunderstood your question and this alone does not solve it however, you could also try assigning the `User` objects id to a property in `AddUserForm` like this:

```
public userId = this.user.id;
```

And changing your ValidationRules and view accordingly:

**ViewModel**

```
ValidationRules
    .ensure((u: AddUserForm) => u.userId)
    .displayName("User")
    .required()
    .on(this);
```

**View**

```
<template>
    <form click.delegate="validate()">
        <input type="text" value.bind="userId & validate" />
    </form>
</template>
```